# How do you patch mock an import from a class that is being imported to a module you are testing?

Tags: python, mocking

The module I am attempting to test (with pytest and pytest-mock) is like so:

x.py

```
from a import ClassA

def a_func():
  class_a = ClassA()
  ...
```

module a.py:

```
import b

class ClassA:
  ...
```

test:

```
def test_my_code(mocker):
  import x
  mock_of_b = mocker.patch.object(x.a, 'b')
  ...
```

or plain unittest:

```
import x

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

  @patch('x.a.b')
  def test_my_code(self, mock_of_b):
  ...
```

I understand that x.a.b isn't going to work because a isn't actually imported - ClassA is but I'm not understanding how can I accomplish patching b in module a when importing ClassA directly.  x.ClassA.b won't work - is there some kind of param to access an imported classes module?  I could grab `__module__` but that's just the string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are making some mistakes. Take a look at a simple setup of a module + mock + function environment.

**person.py**

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
```

**function.py**

```
from person import Person

def show_person(name):
    person = Person(name)
    return "The person name is {}".format(person.get_name())
```

**test.py**

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock
from function import show_person

class TestPerson(TestCase):
    def test_person(self):
        with mock.patch('function.Person.get_name', return_value="bpreisler") as mock_person:
            self.assertEqual(show_person("John"), "The person name is bpreisler")
```

Comment: if you add an import to person.py
`import b`
how would you mock b through function.py?

Comment: Let's say you use `from module_b import function_b` inside **person.py**. As you are testiing the **function.py**, you can mock `person.function_b`  because it is part of **person.py**